# Forward difference operator eigenvalues and eigenfunction in $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, solution-verification, finite-differences

I would be greatful to someone famililar with operator theory to verify if my though process and calculations are correct.

Consider $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and consider the following finite difference operator

\begin{equation}
\Delta_1[f(x)] = f(x+1)-f(x)
\end{equation}

where $f: \mathbb{Z}_{+}\mapsto \mathbb{R}_+$.

I'm interest in computing the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $\Delta_1$. In particular I'll try the following eigenfunction

\begin{equation}
e(x)=x^n, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>}
\end{equation}

from the defintion of $\Delta_1$ it follows that

\begin{equation}
\Delta_1[e(x)] = \Delta_1[x^n] = x^{n+1}-x^{n} = x x^{n}-x^{n} = x^{n}(x-1)
\end{equation}

in other words the eigenvalue $\lambda$ would be $\lambda = (x-1)$ and the eigenfunction $e(x) = x^{n}$

Are the steps correct or is the computation of the eigenvalue not correct as it depends upon $x$?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Sorry, what is the question exactly for which you want to verify your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is $n$, so your computation is correct. And you can show that those are exactly the possible eigenfunctions: that is, if $\Delta_1 f=\lambda f$, then you get (by evaluating at $n$)
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)=\lambda f(n).
$$
That is, $f(n+1)=(\lambda+1)f(n)$. Iterating this you get 
$$
f(n)=(\lambda+1)^{n-1}f(1). 
$$
So, for any given $\lambda\in\mathbb R_+$ there is an eigenfunction $f$, given by $$f(n)=(\lambda+1)^{n-1}.$$ The computation also shows that the eigenspace for each $\lambda$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much.
From what I understand and anlogous reasinig would hold for the one step back operator but I would have to adopt a change of variable to show it?

$f(n-1)=(\lambda+1)f(n)$ with $m = n-1$ hence $\frac{f(m)}{\lambda+1}=f(m+1)$ hence the eigenfunction would be $(\frac{1}{\lambda+1})^{m-1}$

Comment: Moreover, are the eigen functions unique?

Comment: Eigenfunctions are never unique. But in both cases the eigenspaces are one-dimensional.